# Free multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

So I have a simple enough console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I've built it with release configuration. When I run it and open task manager, I see it
has 4 threads. Why is this happening even though I'm not creating any threads?

This can't possibly be each application. I tried opening notepad and it has just 1 thread. Although it is a native app and my console app is managed.

Any ideas?

Comment: You always have at least 1 thread for GC + your main thread.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I imagine threads you are seeing are:

1. The main thread.
2. The finalizer thread
3. The [In-process debugger helper thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384548.aspx)
4. The concurrent GC thread.

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yunjin/archive/2005/07/05/435726.aspx) details some of the special CLR threads.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Excellent resources!

Answer (score 6):

These are .NET Framework threads created for an application, you can use Visual Studio 2010 Threads debug window to see which threads belongs to an application under the question.

Just created a basic console application with empty main method and we can see that 8 threads were created:

[image]

See interesting discussion regarding CLR internal threads here: [The CLR's internal threads](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxtoolsdev/thread/3a821c91-0d8e-486c-8fd6-1a2a85804920)

BTW, notepad is not a .NET Framework application

Comment: I know, so it is impossible to create a single threaded .NET app?

Comment: I believe no since you have no such control over .NET Framework behaviour just wondering whether anyone knows any way of doing this, I'm talking about managed applications, not sure about unmanaged

Comment: I can confirm that a native app (C/C++) has just one thread. Just tried it out.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET Framework always starts some threads at the beginning of a program:

1. Your main thread (obviously)
2. Garbage collection thread
3. JIT thread.

Answer (score 1):

There is one basic difference between a normal COM application and a Managed Application. This is the Garbage Collection.

Each process has a Finalizer Thread associated with it, such that the Finalizers in your application runs only on that Thread.

So the Threads are : 
1. Main Thread (which your application has created)
2. Finalizer Thread (used by garbage collector.
3. JIT Thread (used to JIT code on fly)

The other threads can be SysEvents etc.